Other than rockets, have internal combustion engines run in space?
According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Cryogenic_Evolved_Stage

The  Advanced Cryogenic Evolved Stage (ACES) .. proposed (using) a lightweight internal
combustion engine to use hydrogen and oxygen propellant boil-off
(normally wasted when boil-off gases are vented to space) ... The design included producing power, maintaining stage
attitude[10][14] and keeping the propellant tanks autogenously
pressurized. Using these fluids was designed to eliminate the need for
hydrazine fuel, helium for pressurization,[7][15]: 4, 5  and nearly
all batteries in the vehicle.

Other sources claimed the exhaust was used for settling tanks and attitude control as well. ICE are particularly well adapted for orbital fuel depots since they can operate from boil-off gasses.
The paper: Internal Combustion Engine Solar Independent Propulsion https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/10.2514/6.2019-3964
Proposed a 2-stroke ICE to serve as range extenders on lunar probes which are designed to operate in lunar Permanently Shadowed Regions. Their design had higher specific power and longer loiter time than the option which used Li batteries or fuel cells.
ICE engines running on rocket propellant are at risk of running “metal rich” on stoichiometric mixtures of oxygen and fuel due to high combustion temperatures. This is addressed in this answer from Methane internal combustion engines for rovers on Mars and Moon. Feasibility?

SpaceX has already developed one CH4/O2 ICE: The Raptor. We don’t
usually think of liquid fueled rockets as ICEs, but they are:
compression, ignition, expansion and all that. It is very difficult to
run an ICE on oxygen (as opposed to air) due to the extremely high
combustion temperatures when run stoichiometrically. Air-breathing
hydrocarbon-burning ICEs (like auto engines) don’t need to deal with
this complexity since air is 80% N2. This lowers combustion
temperatures. Raptor’s solution for their preburners is enlightening:
they are run either very rich or very lean to reduce combustion
temperature. The exhaust from the two turbine preburners are then
mixed to burn the uncombusted fuel (from one turbine) and oxygen (from
the other). This solution could be applied to CH4/O2 ICE.


A CH4/O2 ICE on Mars will need to deal with the combustion temperature issue. It
could be dealt with by the same strategy as the Raptor: staged
combustion. A three cylinder engine could have different mixtures in
each cylinder. One would be CH3-rich, the second O2 rich. Exhaust from
each would feed into the third cylinder for completion of combustion.

So far, just talk. Have there been any ICE engines which have operated in space, except for rockets?
Edit: Definition of an internal combustion engine: Combustion products are the working fluid (Otto, Diesel, gas turbine, rocket) as opposed to external combustion engines where the working fluid is not (Sterling engines, steam engines)

Do you consider turbo pumps to be part of the rocket engine?

I suspect there are some hydranzine powered Hydraulic pump units that might be a count, but unsure how many where oscillating piston vs turbine.

@GremlinWranger and Jörg - although maybe not authoritative, Wikipedia lists three categories of ICE - reciprocating (piston-cylinder), rotary, and continuous combustion. Under the continuous combustion subcategory it only lists gas turbine, ramjet, scramjet, and rocket engines. So apparently at least in some definitions ICE does not seem to include pumps, even if combustion takes place inside the pump.

related to some extent: How might an internal combustion engine generate substantial external thrust? and Closed oxygen cycle methane-burning internal combustion engine for Titan rover/helicopter? Works like a battery together with RTG that won't freeze? and Methane internal combustion engines for rovers on Mars and Moon. Feasibility?

@StevePemberton GremlinWranger is probably referring to something like the shuttle orbiter's Auxiliary Power Units which were hydrazine monopropellant fueled units turning a turbine that powered the orbiter's hydraulic pumps through a gearbox.  This could probably be considered some kind of internal combustion engine but I have no stomach for arguments about definitions. See https://space.stackexchange.com/a/57941/6944

@OrganicMarble - the question specifically states internal combustion engine so I think the definition is important since it is a constraint of the question. Even allowing that turbopumps can be considered internal combustion engines there is still the issue that the question states "except rockets" and uses examples that seem to all involve reciprocating engines. Raptor preburner is mentioned (and identified as ICE), but presumably that is being considered part of "rockets" since it could otherwise be an answer itself. Perhaps the question needs to be clarified as to what is excluded.

@StevePemberton ... the Wikipedia definition of ICE was edited into OP. "Reciprocating parts" are not used in the definition since they are neither necessary (Wankle, turbine) nor sufficient (Sterling engines) for the definition.

@JörgWMittag ... yes, turbo pumps are part of the rocket engine. But they can  be ICE_powered (most of them) or electrically driven (Rocket Lab's Rutherford rocket)

With the clarification, then yes, "internal combustion engines" (ICE) as defined in the question have flown in space over 100 times.
Each space shuttle orbiter had three of these ICE installed. They were misnamed the Auxiliary Power Units (APUs) in analogy to aircraft units, but for the shuttle they were the only source of hydraulic power.
Referring to this schematic...

(APU Fam Manual)
...one may see that the APU utilized pump-fed hydrazine which passed through some pulsing speed control valves onto a catalyst bed. The combustion products passed through a gas turbine which was linked via a gearbox to a hydraulic pump.
The APUs were somewhat problematic over the life of the program notably almost destroying Columbia on STS-9 with two of them catching fire and then exploding during entry. An effort to replace them with battery-driven electric motors stalled out before it ever flew.
The APUs were started prelaunch because the Space Shuttle Main Engines required hydraulic power for gimbaling and to move the valves in their control system. After residual propellants were dumped through the engines post-Main Engine Cutoff, the APUs were shut down. Late in the mission one was started for a checkout of the entry flight control systems. On entry day, one APU was started prior to the deorbit burn, and the others were started after the burn before the vehicle needed aerosurface control.
The training manual APU/HYD/WSB Workbook is available online and gives much more detail.
Similar-but-not-exactly-the-same units provided hydraulic power for the Solid Rocket Booster (SRB) thrust vector control systems, and still do for the Space Launch System SRBs.
Information on the hydraulic pump being driven by this ICE is available here: Has any piston machine been used on a space mission?

Interesting answer. Like most people, when I hear "ICE" I think of automobile engines.
